# Fill Color in Specific Part of Image but with Touch only and not with FloodFill

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am making an Android app for colour book, where I have various images with different parts, and when user touch on it - it will be coloured.

I have seen so many answers here for this question but all of them uses **Flood Fill** algorithm. I don't want to fulfill that part with only one touch, I want the user should fill it with his touch, as a painter uses his brush.

I am using Canvas' onTouchEvent, OnDraw etc. methods for getting the touched area painted, but when user draw his finger outside specific part of image, that part also get colored (even the outer part of Image also gets colored when user touch the background).

I want the user can only paint the specific area of that image and that area will not be fullfilled by only one touch (as FloodFill does), it should be painted as a painter paints with his brush.

Can anybody give me some advice how I can implement what I want?

Answer (score 1):

```
    canvas.save()
    canvas.clipRect(rect) or canvas.clipPath(path)
    canvas.drawPath(path)
    canvas.restore()
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**